# Get an uniform distributed sample but keep the order

Tags: r, vector, random, sample, sampling

How could i get a sample of a values of a vector but keep the order without compairing the values themself against each other?

for example:

```
V1 contains values (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
```

I woule like to get a sample

```
sample <- (2,7,10,14)
```

As you can see the values are still on order but randomly selected.

But if i use a function sample or rdunif in R I get random orderd selection:

```
ie. (7,10,2,14)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the following solution you do not compare the elements of your original vector in order to sort them; the only thing you do is shuffling a vector of logical values (`TRUE` or `FALSE`).

Let's say you want to pick `n` elements from the already-ordered vector `v` and maintain their order. Then you can do

```
v <- 1:14
n <- 4

set.seed(42)   # for reproducibility
logi <- sample(c(rep(TRUE, n), rep(FALSE, length(v) - n)))
v[logi]
# [1]  1  6  7 14
```

---

**EDIT** to prove that the vector `v` can be any vector, and we still manage to maintain its original order.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 4
v <- sample(14, replace = FALSE)
v
# [1]  9  4  7  1  2 12  3  6 10  8  5 11 13 14

set.seed(42)   # for reproducibility
logi <- sample(c(rep(TRUE, n), rep(FALSE, length(v) - n)))
v[logi]
# [1]  9 12  3 14
```

These numbers respect indeed the original order of vector `v`.

Comment: This also fails if the original `V1` is not in numerical order.  Even if the OP  really just wants that (why would he  :-) ),  it's not a solution of general use.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I believe you are mistaken, and that the original vector `v` does not need to be in numerical order. Please have a look at my example in the edit, I still believe I'm correct

Comment: @RicS  My apologies - you are correct. Somehow when I ran your solution, I replaced `v` with something other than the original `v` in use.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No problem, thanks for making me double-check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if we can't do this when the original `V1` is not in numerical order.

```
set.seed(42)
 v <- sample(1:14,14,rep=FALSE)
 #  [1]  1  5 14  9 10  4  2  8 12 11  6 13  7  3
 n <- 4
 foo <- sample(v,length(v)-n,rep=FALSE)
 match(foo,v)
 v[-match(foo,v)]
 # [1]  1 13  7  3
```

Now the output sample values are in the same order they are in the original vector.

Comment: I suspect this is functionally identical to RicS solution

Answer (score -1):

```r
V1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
sample_V1 <- sample(V1, 4)
sort(sample_V1)
```

Comment: Thank you but sadly your proposal will not work since i dont want to compare the values of vector as such to bring the order so the solution should work independent of the values themself.